# Xcode 4: same navigation view for all tabs

Tags: xcode

There is a way to let the navigation view (red box in figure) be the same for all tabs opened?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: As a Netbeans programmer, it is very annoying for me this view changing at each tab click. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I could see how that would be annoying. I do not believe there is a way to force this but when opening a new tab the Navigation panel will be in the same state as the current tab you are on. So if you open a new tab with the Navigation panel present the tab will be showing the navigation panel as well (and vise versa). So it is easy to have all of your tabs consistent.

I believe the rationale for not forcing this to be the same across multiple tabs is because it is often nice to have the tabs different. In one tab you may just have one file open but in another if you are using the Assistant Editor (showing two files at the same time) it is nice to have this hidden. With tabs this can be automatic for you because each tab can have different navigation panels present.

Yes, it would be nice to have a setting for this and maybe eventually they will have one. There is also an easy shortcut to hide the navigation panel: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>